# Use str.replace() input in output

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

In JavaScript, how can I use all or part of the matched string in the new string.  For example: I have the following two strings:

```
var str1 = "Hello, my name is Vinnie Caprarola";
var str2 = "Hello, my name is John Doe";
var str3 = "Hello, my name is very weird";
```

I would like to surround the names with a span element, so apply a 'name' class to the names.  Assume that this is not all of the string, and could have characters before and after.  Also, like in `str3`, if the part after 'Hello, my name is ' is not capitalized, I should assume it is not a name and ignore it.  So my question is: how can I run the exact same function on all of these strings and get this output:

```
var str1 = "Hello, my name is <span>Vinnie Caprarola</span>";
var str2 = "Hello, my name is <span>John Doe</span>";
var str3 = "Hello, my name is very weird";
```

So, I would need to replace the name with basically `'<span>' + name + '</span>'`.  How do I get `name` in the previous expression?

Comment: That's precisely the question that you need to *answer* instead of asking: how does the computer know that "John Doe" is what you call a "name", and "very weird" is not?

Comment: They want a regex that will only match Capitalized names.

Comment: You could use a regex like this: http://regex101.com/r/lU8eI0/1 but I think it might be too brittle

Comment: @Jon - I am assuming that if it is capitalized, it is a name.  This is an example only for the question.  The actual thing I am doing is much more complex, but I wanted to just get what I needed from the question.

Comment: @VinnieCaprarola: I highly doubt that you are going to get what you need from a vague question. Also, your assumption is obviously incorrect if taken literally -- "Louis van Gaal" is an easy example.

Comment: @Jon is right, even if you cold conceive of a regex that managed to match all of the edge cases it would only live as long as you never encountered new data.  My guess is the best approach is a function that looks like "non names"

Comment: Or Mets catcher [Travis d'Arnaud](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702303491404579391292491338268)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer!

As I read [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), you can specify a function as the replace parameter, with the match in that function.  So make the function look like this:

```
function doTheReplace(match) {
  return '<span>' + match + '</span>';
}

str1.replace(/Hello\, my name is [A-Z].* [A-Z].* /, doTheReplace);
str2.replace(/Hello\, my name is [A-Z].* [A-Z].* /, doTheReplace);
str3.replace(/Hello\, my name is [A-Z].* [A-Z].* /, doTheReplace);
```

And this will produce the requested output.

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it.

```
string.replace(/(?!^)([A-Z]\w+ ?)+/g, '<span>$&</span>');
```

Comment: It's close, if you use this regex `/([A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*)/` then it works. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/0Lexpvee/

Comment: Oh whoops, I didn't notice he wanted a span around the entire name. I'll update.

Comment: Actually if you change it slightly more to `/([A-Z][a-z\s]* [A-Z][a-z\s]*)/` then you can get the `Louis van Gaal` example :) [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/0Lexpvee/1/)

Comment: That won't work on a longer string like "My name is Louis van Gaal" though.

Comment: Here is how you appease the Mets: `/([A-Z][a-z\s\\']*[A-Z][a-z\s\\']*)/` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/0Lexpvee/2/ (and it works on the longer names as well) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good start:

```
var str1 = "Hello, my name is Vinnie Caprarola";
var str2 = "Hello, my name is John Doe";
var str3 = "Hello, my name is very weird";
var str4 = "Hello, my name is Louis van Gaal";

var re = /Hello,\smy\sname\sis\s([A-Z]\w+.*[A-Z]\w+)/;
function addSpan(origStr) {
    return origStr.replace(re, 'Hello, my name is <span>$1</span>');
};

console.log(addSpan(str1)); //Hello, my name is <span>Vinnie Caprarola</span> 
console.log(addSpan(str2)); //Hello, my name is <span>John Doe</span> 

console.log(addSpan(str3)); //Hello, my name is very weird 
console.log(addSpan(str4)); //Hello, my name is <span>Louis van Gaal</span>
```

You can use the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dywe8Ln5/2/

Hopefully this gets you started.  Use the MDN article on regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for a definitive guide to javascript regular expressions.

@nicklaw, your answer is close, but the questions says that there may be more content besides this portion of the string.  Therefore, you cannot be certain that every capitalized word followed by another capitalized word is a name.

Comment: One of the comments mentioned that the string would be much more complicated, which I assume would mean it wouldn't necessarily start with "Hello my name is"... While not perfect, I think mine would handle more use cases.

Comment: What about the string: "I live in San Francisco, Hello, my name is Bob Johnson."  This function correctly surrounds only Bob Johnson.

Comment: But it doesn't work with "Hi, call me Bob Johnson". Yours is right as long as the string never changes.

Comment: The OP says, "I am assuming that if it is capitalized, it is a name."

Comment: It shouldn't need to be said, but it's trivial to break this: "Hello, my name is Jack and I live in Barcelona" etc.